# Why my typing cursor moves to the beginning when typing period in HTML number input?

Tags: javascript, html

`<input type="number" oninput="this.value=this.value.slice(0,5)"/>`

I'm trying to limit the number of char allowed in the field, but when typing period, the cursor moves to the beginning and the period symbol is not typed?

How can I fix this behavior?

Thanks

Specified oninput field to slice the value of input field, it worked fine but when typing period symbol the cursors moves to the front, it doesn't do that the second time.

[image]

Comment: Why not use the `maxlength` attribute to limit the number of characters?

Comment: Regardless, I can't recreate this. When I type a period, the cursor stays where it was.

Comment: maxlength doesn't limit the character number for me.  Possible browser specific?  I'm using Chrome 120.0.6

Comment: Decimal is allowed in number input per this msdn article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#allowing_decimal_values

Comment: I imagine the browser is parsing the string value you provide as a number, and e.g. `"111."` would become just `111` if there's nothing after the `.`

Comment: Your problem is that `this.value` returns a parsed value. If the user enters "1." you get "1", without the trailing dot. When you assign that string to the control, the current position of the cursor becomes invalid since the assigned string is shorter than the current string, and it is set to the beginning of the string. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Your real problem is that you assign the value read from `this.value` to `this.value`. The string you get isn't exactly what the user has typed. For example, if the user have typed "1." you get the parsed value "1", without the trailing dot. And since your assign that value to the control, and the length of that value is shorter than the current value, the current position of the control is lost and it is reset to 0, the beginning of the control. That's why the cursor moves to the first position when you enter a decimal separator.

If the input has an invalid character, it returns a empty string. Chrome and Edge filters what characters are allowed. Firefox doesn't. Chrome allows both decimal comma and decimal dot to be used, but the returned value always uses a dot.

You can test it below:

```html
<input id="wrong" type="number" oninput="console.log(this.value)" />
```

Since the behavior of the input of type number is browser specific, I usually set the type to text. Then the `maxlength` will be honored if supported and you will not need to modify the element. You can parse the value when you read it in your code.

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('input[name=usernumber]');

// Only allow digits and a period
elem.addEventListener('beforeinput', (event) => {
  const key = event.data;
  if (!((key === '.' && elem.value.indexOf('.') < 0) || (key >= '0' && key <= '9'))) event.preventDefault();
  // you can add additional checks
});


// parsing the value
elem.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  console.log('The value', parseFloat(elem.value))
});
```

```css
input:invalid {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
 <input name="usernumber" type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="\d*(\.\d*)?" maxlength="5" />
```

`inputmode="numeric"` is a hint to the browser what keyboard to display.

`pattern="\d*"` tells the browser what input is valid. Note: You can still enter illagal characters, but then the field is invalid, and you can show that with some css.

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor moves to end of the inputElements because you slice up them every function call.
Now you need to find current cursor position, calculate your given inputElement.length. before this calculation you need find your valid digits value which you want retain. I use regx for this and slice up to your length. then calculate valid digits values.length - inputElement.length. and selection start from input element to this.

```js
function limitsLength(inputElement, maxLength) {
                        let sanitizedValue = inputElement.value.replace(/\D/g, '').slice(0, maxLength);
                        let cursorPos = inputElement.selectionStart + (sanitizedValue.length - inputElement.value.length);

                        inputElement.value = sanitizedValue;
                        inputElement.setSelectionRange(cursorPos, cursorPos);
                    }
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="limitsLength(this, 5)" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by adding a conditional before the slice.

```
<input type="number" oninput="if (this.value.length > 5) this.value=this.value.slice(0,5)"/>
```

Thanks for your help everyone.